# Why does the kinesis shard iterator falls behind when using BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, amazon-kinesis

I'm using KDA with a flink job which should analyse messages emitted by a different IOT device sources. There is a kinesis stream with 4 shards with each of them contains more or less the same amount of data (there are no hot shards). The kinesis stream gets filled by AWS Greengrass Streammanager which is using an increasing sequence number as partition key. Each message contains a single value (something like temperature = 5).

As with this setup the stream read by the kinesis consumer in flink is unordered. But I need to preserve the order of the messages. To do so I have written a small buffer function which is more or less the logic from [CepOperator](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-libraries/flink-cep/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/cep/operator/CepOperator.java) to buffer messages and restore the order. Therefore the stream is keyed by the id of a message. Let's say a temperature message has always a unique id and therefore the stream is keyed by this id.

To create the respective watermarks I'm using the `FlinkKinesisConsumer` and register there a `BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor`. If I now use a `out-of-orderness` time of *10 seconds* everything works fine except that I have almost 50% of late arrivals which is not the desired behaviour. But now if I increase the time to *60 seconds* the iterator of the kinesis stream falls significantly behind (linear growing over time). The documentation of the Kinesis Consumer does say a little about the settings [here](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/connectors/datastream/kinesis/#event-time-alignment-for-shard-consumers). I have also tried to register a `JobManagerWatermarkTracker` but it seems that it does not change the behaviour.

I do not understand the circumstances why a higher *out of orderness* leads the iterator to fall behind increasingly but a smaller time setting drops a significant amount of messages. What measures do I need to take to find the proper settings or is my implementation wrong?

*UPDATE:*

While investigating the issue I have found that if the `JobManagerWatermarkTracker` isn't properly configured (I still don't understand how to configure) the alignment to the global watermark stops subtasks from reading from the kinesis stream which causes the iterator to fall back. I have calculated a delta how much "latency" a dropped event has and set this as and *out-of-orderness* (in this case 60 secs). With deactivating the `JobManagerWatermarkTracker` everything work as expected.
Furthermore it seems that the AWS Greengrass Streammanager isn't optimal for such use cases as it distributes the load evenly across shards but with an increasing number of shards this isn't optimal since one *temperature datapoint* might be spread across all shards of a stream. That introduces a lot unnecessary latency. I appreciate any input howto configure the `JobManagerWatermarkTracker`

Comment: While it (most likely) doesn't matter in this situation, do be aware that you're linking to the documentation for the latest version of Flink. KDA still runs on Flink 1.13 so the correct documentation link would be https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/connectors/datastream/kinesis/#event-time-alignment-for-shard-consumers

Comment: this is true. I updated the question

Comment: We had big problems with ordering of events from Kinesis and eventually ended up moving to Kafka (MSK) where the order can actually be guaranteed in the stream. Probably not what you wanted to hear though :(

Comment: @bzu afaik both Apache Kafka & AWS Kinesis guarantee ordering of events on partition / shard level. Neither of them guarantees ordering on topic / stream level.

Comment: As you said, but in Kinesis, you can only make it work with PutRecord, not PutRecords: https://brandur.org/kinesis-order Don't know what Greengrass is doing though.

Comment: Greengrass Streammanager is using a monotonous sequence number as partition key to evenly distribute all records across shards which makes no sense in our use case. As the stream manager api does not provide a property to set the partition key it might be not a proper choice

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/v2/developerguide/work-with-streams.html